# jQuery - load from another page after all elements are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-load

I want to display the rating of a product, witch is on the product page in div with id rating, on the category page, so I made a script below:

```
$('.product').each(function(){
    var url = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    $(this).prepend('<div class="rating"></div>');
    $(this).find('.rating').load(url +'#rating');
});
```

The problem is, that the rating on the product page is generated with another script, so the element #rating is not present on the site from the start, so after doing some search I tried adding ajaxcomplete function:

```
$('.product').each(function(){
    var url = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    $(this).prepend('<div class="rating"></div>');
    $(this).ajaxComplete(function(nxt) {
        $(this).find('.rating').load(url +'#rating');
        nxt();
    });
});
```

But that also doesn't seem to work, so I'm wondering is there any solution for this to work?

Thanks

Comment: Does the other page contain `div#rating`?

Comment: The product page doesn't contain div#rating from the start, it's loaded with script after the page is fully loaded

Comment: Can't you use that same script on your category page?

Comment: So basically you want to know when the ratings script has been executed?

Comment: unfortunately I can't do that, to sum up, this is for AB testing, and the script is not present on the category pages, also some parameters needed for script to work are not available on the category page, and I can't change that I'm afraid

Comment: @Mubix basically I need to get the element from the page after the script has been executed, so yes, I probably need to know that to execute after

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the script that does the rating using jQuery getScript. This way you can put processing dependent on the rating script in the success handler of the getScript call.

The code will look something like this:

```
$.getScript( "rating.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  console.log( "rating complete" );
  $('.product').each(function(){
    var url = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    $(this).find('.rating').load(url +'#rating');
  }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that the script in question is on the product page, not on the category page where I'm running my code, is there any way to run that function for another page?

Comment: So you are basically screen scraping the product page to get the rating?

Comment: Something like that yes

Comment: The .load() call only fetches the HTML of the page and doesnt execute it .. you need to go back to the drawing board and and do this usinf iFrames ... try http://blog.karlwestin.com/2010/05/data-scraping-with-jquery-and-iframe/ as a starting point.

Comment: or this .. http://grasshopperpebbles.com/ajax/using-jquery-to-access-iframe-content/